# I have a WSDL, how do I create (BUT NOT SEND) the SOAP for a request?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, asp.net-core-2.0

My parent company has a WSDL, and I can create a ServiceModel, and use it to invoke web methods, and that's fine. However, what I need is to generate the SOAP XML *without sending it*. So, if I do this:

```
var mySvc = new MyWsdl.MyWebService();
var response = mySvc.DoTheThing(myUser, myData, myOtherData);
```

I know that under the covers, .NET is creating XML and sending it across the wire. But I need that XML *without sending it*, so, ideally, some code like:

```
var mySvc = new MyWsdl.MyWebService();
var xml = mySvc.GetSOAP("DoTheThing", myUser, myData, myOtherData);
```

Is there a way to do this? I am trying to get out of manually generating the XML.

The *reason* I'm doing this is because I need to actually send the SOAP to a different, normal non-SOAP web service. I *suspect* that that service is just going to turn around and call the SOAP service anyway, possibly massage the results, and return something to me, but that's out of my hands. Very soon I will not be able to use the ServiceClient directly.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I would like to do this *programatically*. Otherwise, yes, I can get the XML by capturing a sent request, or using an app like SoapUI, but then I'm still manually creating the XML. The idea is, that if the WSDL changes, I don't want to have to change the XML I generate, so if the service client can do it for me, that would be ideal.

Comment: I have found out for this type of things SoapUI extremely useful.

Comment: This answer may sound silly.  Create you own local server and send it to yourself.

Comment: @bradbury9: Thanks, I just edited the answer to say that I wanted to do this programatically. I used Soap UI to generate the "shell" for my current implementation, but I still have to manually maintain that XML.

Comment: @jdweng - thanks, I have the XML shape, I want to generate it programatically. I edited my question to reflect that. Or are you saying, I should publish the WSDL on my own, capture the request, and THEN do what I want with it? That might work ... but it sounds like the long way around.

Comment: That is what I'm saying to do programatically. You can create a simply server and then send to your server and capture the request in the server.